# Creating a method for search product by name in "ProductModel" class and display it in panel with image buttons and labels

Tags: c#, asp.net

ProductModel.cs: (class)

This is my productmodel class which searches product by name. Check if it is correct or not.

```
  public static Product SearchProductsByName(string Name, List<Product>     products)
  {
    Product pd;
    pd = new Product();
    foreach (Product rs in products)
    {
        if (Name == rs.Name)
        {
            return pd;
        }
    }
    return null;    // <<< Return a value if nothing was found
   }
```

Search.aspx:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />

 <br />

<asp:Panel ID="pnlProducts" runat="server">
    <br />
</asp:Panel>
```

Search.aspx.cs   (i want to display the searched product using Searched product ty name method)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();

    List<Product> products = productModel.SearchProductsByName**(txtSearch.text);** //getting error here



    //make sure product exist in the db
    if (products != null)
    {
        //create a new panel with an image btn & 2 labels
        foreach (Product product in products)
        {
            Panel productPanel = new Panel();
            ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
            Label lblName = new Label();
            Label lblPrice = new Label();
```

Comment: What is the exception you get ? And what is your question ?

Comment: getting error in    List<Product> products = productModel.SearchProductsByName(txtSearch.text);                                         'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extension method 'text' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Try : `txtSearch.Text`

Comment: Also, your code is a little confusing, when do you retrieve data from the database (or whatever datasource) ? You should also provide a list of products for, like this (to adapt to your needs) : `SearchProductsByName(txtSearch.Text, products)`

Comment: now it gives "no over load method for SearchproductsbByName takes one arguments

Comment: Please refer to my previous comment. Check your method, you need to provided two parameters.

Comment: tell me the correct method plz?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a `List<Product> products` to a function that does not return a `List<Product>`

So logically what you are supposed to have is a function that returns a List like this:

```
public static List<Product> SearchProductsByName()
{
      // Do work
      // Return List<Product>
}
```

So thats one of the problems. The other would be that your `SearchProductsByName` function takes two arguments and you are only providing one =>

```
productModel.SearchProductsByName**(txtSearch.text)
```

So what you are missing there is variable of type `List<Product>` as you defined it in your `SearchProductsByName` function.

Comment: lol..! Looking at your code and what you are trying to achieve, your SearchProductsByName is supposed to return a single product, exactly the way you have it. Then in your btnSearch_Click function, you must assign SearchProductsByName to an instance of Product like this 'Product myProduct = SearchProductsByName(your two arguments go here)'. Then if your class Product has a list of images you must loop through those images and not the product.